# Jenkins Token Macro - How to set a value based on date

Tags: jenkins

I would like to set a custom variable accessible via the token macro plugin based off the current time.

(eg how would I get a template say ${CUSTOM} evaluate to a value of 'TRUE' from 9am to 5pm and then to 'FALSE' otherwise?)

Do I need to write my own plugin?  Or can this be done via other Jenkins plugins?

Thanks for any help, just at a loss here.